# Gmail App - responsive signature (media queries)

Tags: html, css, gmail, newsletter

Is it possible to code an HTML responsive signature for Gmail?
I am trying use the media queries, but it's not working on the web client or Gmail Android App.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's but not with media queries.

The problem is that some e-mail clients stripe all `<style>...</style>` tags out. If I remember correctly, GMail is no exception.

So, yes, you can build responsive layout by using inline CSS with values in `%` but it will be *completely* responsive then. It is to say it will absolutely depend on the parent container size.

However, your e-mail signature will unlikely ever appear out of e-mail (which is the parent container), so, you just need to check that the signature looks nice at least in most popular screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks, so... best practice is vertical email signature. No breakpoints needed.

Comment: @AdamŘezníček well, certainly only inline CSS is possible. Also, please note that neither some of CSS features (like flex box for instance) will work in e-mails. I'd recommend you to check your markup with a specialized tool like, [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) for instance.